# How to set an Integer Variable to set Reset within a number of seconds

Tags: c#, emgucv

The method below processing rectangles for the objects identified in findPedestrian() method. I have assigned 'rectCount' variable to show the rectangle count on every each frame. And 'maxCount' variable shows the maximum number of rectangles the count while the process.

```
private Image<Bgr, Byte> imagingPedestrian(Image<Bgr, Byte> image)
    { 
        System.Drawing.Rectangle[] results = pedestrianDetection.findPedestrian(image);
        //System.Drawing.Rectangle[] results2 = vehicleDetection.findVehicle(image);
        foreach (Rectangle rect in results)
        {
            CvInvoke.Rectangle(image, rect, new Bgr(Color.Red).MCvScalar);
            rectCount = results.Count();
            label1.Text = rectCount.ToString();
            if(rectCount > maxCount1)
            {
                maxCount1 = rectCount;
                label8.Text = maxCount1.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                label8.Text = maxCount1.ToString();
            }
        }
        return image;
    }
```

In this question what i want to get is get the rectangle count for every 10 seconds. After 10 seconds the maxCount variable should get reset. Then it should show the maximum rectangle count within next 10 seconds. Like wise it should run iterately within every 10 seconds. Is there anyway to implement it..

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: _"Is there anyway to implement it"_ -- yes, of course. It's programming. If you can state in precise terms what you want to accomplish, it can be done. What have you tried already? As stated, your question is far too broad. Please provide a good [mcve] showing what you've tried and a precise, detailed explanation of what specifically you are having trouble with. You can use `Stopwatch` to track elapsed time or one of the several `Timer` classes in .NET to periodically execute some code.

Comment: I will point out that computing a trailing maximum (i.e. max over the last 10 seconds) is more useful/common than resetting the max every 10 seconds.

Comment: @PeterDuniho ok let's say i have an integer variable which has assigned a value into it. How can i reset it to 0 after 10 seconds,

Answer (score 0):

Add a [timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) to your form. You can drag it from the toolbox onto your form, or as the documentation demonstrates, you can just declare it in your form. You can set the `Interval` property to 10000 (that's 10 seconds in milliseconds) and set `Enabled` to true or call the `Start()` method.

Then add a handler for the `Tick` event. That event gets raised every time the interval elapses. Within that handler you can perform your updates.

Comment: You're right. My link was broken, but I was referring to the windows forms timer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to use [**System.Timer**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Example from MSDN:

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

public class Example
{
   private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

   public static void Main()
   {
      SetTimer();

      Console.WriteLine("\nPress the Enter key to exit the application...\n");
      Console.WriteLine("The application started at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}", DateTime.Now);
      Console.ReadLine();
      aTimer.Stop();
      aTimer.Dispose();

      Console.WriteLine("Terminating the application...");
   }

   private static void SetTimer()
   {
        // Create a timer with a two second interval.
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}",
                          e.SignalTime);
    }
}

// The example displays output like the following:
//       Press the Enter key to exit the application...
//
//       The application started at 09:40:29.068
//       The Elapsed event was raised at 09:40:31.084
//       The Elapsed event was raised at 09:40:33.100
//       The Elapsed event was raised at 09:40:35.100
//       The Elapsed event was raised at 09:40:37.116
//       The Elapsed event was raised at 09:40:39.116
//       The Elapsed event was raised at 09:40:41.117
//       The Elapsed event was raised at 09:40:43.132
//       The Elapsed event was raised at 09:40:45.133
//       The Elapsed event was raised at 09:40:47.148
//
//       Terminating the application...
```

As you can see, you create a timer, set AutoReset to true so it resets each time when achieving the needed value, and also subscribe your method to event so each time when the timer passes it will execute needed code.

Just apply the same approach to your application and your problem should be solved.

Comment: My answer originally stated that the `Tick` event would not be raised on the UI thread, but I was wrong (fixed it.) But if you use the `System.Timer.Timers` class then that is the case - the `Elapsed` event occurs on a different thread. So in that case you would need to make sure that any updates to the UI were done on the UI thread.

Comment: @ScottHannen Thanks for adding clarification!